# phil's rest server before action

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I am creating a rest service. I have done all the required methods, what I want to do is some authorization. I have created the table where I store the api-keys, i load them in each method, and it works quite well.
What I need now, is to do some before action that would be called before each method, so i don't have to check if the user is successfully authorized on each method? In simple CI_Controller or in FuelPHP that can be done using public function before, but I dont know how to achieve the same thing in REST_Controller?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you can do it in the constructer. constructer is initialized before the method runs

Comment: Yes of course, but I forgot to mention that I will need to get some GET values from the constructor, and that is not allowed from constructor.

Comment: also hooking is possible take a look here http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/76228/

Answer (score 1):

Here are two controllers. May give you some idea

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    protected $before_filter    =   array();
    protected $after_filter     =   array();    

    private function run_filter($who, $params=array()) 
    {
        $filter =   $this->{"{$who}_filter"};

        if (is_string($filter)) {
            $filter =   array($filter);
        }

        if (method_exists($this, "{$who}_filter")) {
            $filter[]   =   "{$who}_filter";
        }

        foreach ($filter as $method) {
            call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
        }
    }
    public function _remap($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (method_exists($this, $method))
        {
            $this->run_filter('before', $parameters);
            $return =   call_user_func_array(array($this, $method),$parameters);
            $this->run_filter('after', $parameters);    
        }else{
            show_404();
        }
    }   
}

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    public $before_filter   =   array('check_login');
    public $after_filter        =   array();    

    private function dashboard() 
    {
        /*  other code here */
    }

    public function check_login() 
    {
        /*  Login checking Code here    */
    }   
}
```